# Control bus: unidirectional or bidirectional?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture

The address bus is unidirectional and the data bus is bidirectional but the jury seems to be out on the control bus:

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Control+bus+is+bidirectional%22

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Control+bus+is+unidirectional%22

I suspect the answer is that it's sometimes unidirectional and sometimes bidirectional. Could someone provide a succinct summary of if/when the control bus is unidirectional or bidirectional?

Edit: I'm a high school teacher and I'm hoping for an answer that is accessible to a high school student. I raise this question because different exam boards give different answers and it would be useful to have an expert opinion.

Comment: Which control bus, i.e. which CPU or chipset / protocol are you talking about?  Part of DDR4 SDRAM?  Or a frontside bus for some CPU, like Intel Core 2 (last gen to use a frontside bus, before integrating the memory controllers into the CPU and using QPI or DMI to connect CPUs to each other and the chipset.)

Comment: Are you considering all signals to be part of some "bus"?  Like external interrupt pins, or a reset signal?  Are you counting it as bidirectional if some signals are unidirection each way, or only if at least some control lines are individually bidirection?  Presumably all buses that allow a device to lock the bus (for atomic RMW) need a bidirectional pin for that.

Comment: What buses are your students learning about?  What angle are you approaching CPU architecture from?  (bottom up boolean logic gates and stuff like 74xx logic chips building up to more complex things you can do, vs. top-down breaking down a CPU into logic blocks and then looking in detail and some aspects, like https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/ but for simpler CPUs?)

Comment: I'm surprised a high-school course has time or background to get into a detail like this at all, and I'm worried this is getting into "here's a fact to memorize" territory.  I know you said "accessible" to students, but if you know how a given bus works, this is something you already can just see from looking for any bidirectional signals on that bus in the specs.  So trying to come up with a generic factoid like this seems like the process of divorcing fact from understanding and turning it into a trivial answer.

Comment: What might be helpful is figuring out why a bus might or might not need bidirectional control signals, once you define whether bidirectional means a single pin whose direction depends on other signals / protocol, or just the existence of signalling in either direction.  And again, what kind of bus you're talking about.  That would give you the understanding necessary to look at what a bus is for, and what connects to it, and think about whether it would need any bidirectional control signalling.  There probably isn't an answer for "control busses" in general that's true for all buses.

Comment: (2 comments ago I meant to write "trivia" not "trivial".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Peter says, it depends on your definition of control bus.

Most control signals are generated from one place and listened to at another rather than bidirectional (even though signals may be going in both directions, just usually not on the same wire).

But embedded processors, like Atmel's atega & AVR, have I/O pins that can be dynamically reconfigured for input vs. output, so these pins fit some definition of bi-directional.

These pins, though, are usually used by the board in only one way, and so on boot, the program initializes the pins for the embedded application, by telling the processor whether each pin is input vs. output.  In practice, this is more configuration rather than bidirectional usage.

Still, some application and board could change the pin direction at will; the generality is there and the processors will allow it.

These I/O pins can be considered data or control (they are used in controlling devices) or both, depending on your definition.